# How to Run TimerTask behind JFrame in java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, timertask

I have a problem with the application (GUI JFrame form Class) that I created, I am trying to run a method that contains commands to perform data scanning using `java.util.TimerTask`. The method I want to run through `JCheckBoxMenuItem` and will run if I tick`checkBoxMenuItem`. The problem is that when I check 'checkBoxMenuItem`, scan method still running but I can not access JFrame (GUI) again.

```
import Database.KoneksiDatabase2;
import Design.ClButtonTransparan;
import Design.JPanelWithImage;
import Proses.Data.DebitDiberikan;
import Proses.Data.DebitKebutuhan;
import Proses.Data.DebitTersedia;
import Proses.Data.AutoScanNReply;
import Proses.Data.CurahHujan;
import Proses.Data.DataKirim;
import Proses.Data.DataMasuk;
import Proses.Data.Faktor_K;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import java.util.Timer;

public class FormPAI extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private JPanel contentPane, panel1, panelJam;
    private JLabel lbtotQs, lbtotQb, lbtotQa, lbfaktorK, lbQa1, lbQa2, lbQa3;
    private JLabel lbQa4, lbQa5, lbQa6, lbQa7, lbQa8, lbQa9, lbQa10, lbQa11;
    private JLabel lbQa12, lbQb1, lbQb2, lbQb3, lbQb4, lbQb5, lbQb6, lbQb7;
    private JLabel lbQb8, lbQb9, lbQb10, lbQb11, lbQb12, lbTotQ;
    private JButton btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6;
    //public Timer timer2 = null;
    private JPopupMenu popUp;
    private JMenuItem tulisPesan, inbox, kotakKeluar, pesanTerkirim;
    ActionListener aksi, aksiTulisPesan, aksiInbox, aksikotakKeluar, aksiPesanTerkirim;
    private Timer timer;

    public FormPAI() throws IOException, SQLException {

        initComponents();
        setTitle("Pembagian Air Irigasi");
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 700, 650);
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\X201\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\PembagianAirIrigasi\\src\\img\\bacground3.jpg"));
        contentPane = new JPanelWithImage(img);
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        btnClose();

        BufferedImage imgSkema = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\X201\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\PembagianAirIrigasi\\src\\img\\baturiti3.png"));
        panel1 = new JPanelWithImage(resize(imgSkema, 670, 420));
        panel1.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 1, true));
        panel1.setBounds(5, 115, 680, 425);
        contentPane.add(panel1);

        ClockLabel dateLable = new ClockLabel("date");
        ClockLabel timeLable = new ClockLabel("time");
//        ClockLabel dayLable = new ClockLabel("day");
        panelJam = new JPanel();
        panelJam.setBounds(545, 541, 140, 55);
        panelJam.setBackground(Color.black);
        panelJam.add(timeLable);
        panelJam.add(dateLable);
//        panelJam.add(dayLable);
        contentPane.add(panelJam);

        jCheckBoxMenuItem1.setText("Run Gammu");
        jCheckBoxMenuItem1.setSelected(false);
        jCheckBoxMenuItem1.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Checked? " + jCheckBoxMenuItem1.isSelected());
                int state = e.getStateChange();
                if (state == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                    try {
                        scan();

                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(FormPAI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }else{
                    timer.cancel();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void scan() throws SQLException{

        java.util.TimerTask task = new java.util.TimerTask()  {
            DebitKebutuhan dk = new DebitKebutuhan();
            @Override
            public void run(){
                System.out.println("ajik");
                DataMasuk obj = new DataMasuk();
                DataKirim dkrm = new DataKirim();
                CurahHujan ch = new CurahHujan();
                String cek = null, processed="";

                try {
                    Connection c = KoneksiDatabase2.getKoneksiDBSMS();
                    ResultSet rset = c.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM inbox WHERE Processed='false'").executeQuery();
                    while (rset.next()){
                        cek = rset.getString("ID");
                        processed = rset.getString("Processed");
                    }
                    if (cek != null){
                        obj.ambilTeksPesan();
                        obj.cekFormatPesan();
                        if (obj.formatSMS == true && processed.equals("false")){
                            obj.ambilDataPesan();
                            obj.simpanPesan_ke_DB();
                            obj.sendToDataMasuk();
                            obj.updateDataMasuk();
                            ch.simpanCHKeDB();
                            dkrm.sendToOutbox();
                            obj.tandaiSudahDibalas(cek);
                        }
                    }
                    rset.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        };
        timer = new Timer(true);// true to run timer as daemon thread
        timer.schedule(task, 0, 5000);// Run task every 5 second
        try {
            Thread.sleep(60000*60); // Cancel task after 1 minute.
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        timer.cancel();
    }

    public static BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage img, int newW, int newH) { 
        Image tmp = img.getScaledInstance(newW, newH, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        BufferedImage dimg = new BufferedImage(newW, newH, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Graphics2D g2d = dimg.createGraphics();
        g2d.drawImage(tmp, 0, 0, null);
        g2d.dispose();

        return dimg;
    }


    public final void btnClose(){
        ImageIcon idt = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\X201\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\PembagianAirIrigasi\\src\\img\\exit.png");
        Image imgRoll = idt.getImage();
        Image newImgRoll = imgRoll.getScaledInstance(65, 65, 100);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\X201\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\PembagianAirIrigasi\\src\\img\\shutdown.png");
        Image img = icon.getImage();
        Image newimg = img.getScaledInstance(65, 65, 100);
        btn6 = new ClButtonTransparan("<html><center>"+"KELUAR"+"</center></html>");
        btn6.setFont(new Font("Berlin Sans FB Demi", Font.PLAIN,12));
        btn6.setBounds(555, 5, 105, 105); // posisi jbutton (x, y) dan ukurunnnya (lebar, tinggi)
        btn6.setIcon(new ImageIcon(newimg));
        btn6.setRolloverIcon(new ImageIcon (newImgRoll));
        btn6.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM); //membuat text jbutton berada dibawah
        btn6.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER); //membuat text jbutton berada ditengah
    contentPane.add(btn6);
        btn6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, menuBar);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }




    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jCheckBoxMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jMenu1.setText("File");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

        jMenu2.setText("Edit");

        jCheckBoxMenuItem1.setSelected(true);
        jCheckBoxMenuItem1.setText("jCheckBoxMenuItem1");
        jCheckBoxMenuItem1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jCheckBoxMenuItem1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenu2.add(jCheckBoxMenuItem1);

        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jCheckBoxMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   

    }                                                  

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FormPAI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                    FormPAI frame = new FormPAI();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    //frame.scan();
                }catch(Exception e){
                }
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem jCheckBoxMenuItem1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
class ClockLabel extends JLabel implements ActionListener {

  String type;
  SimpleDateFormat sdf;

  public ClockLabel(String type) {
    this.type = type;
    setForeground(Color.green);

    switch (type) {
      case "day"  : sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE  ");
                    setFont(new Font("Digital-7", Font.PLAIN, 14));
                    setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
                    break;
      case "time" : sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
                    setFont(new Font("sans-serif", Font.PLAIN, 16));
                    setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                    break;
      case "date" : sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");
                    setFont(new Font("sans-serif", Font.PLAIN, 20));
                    setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                    break;
      default     : sdf = new SimpleDateFormat();
                    break;
    }

    javax.swing.Timer t = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, this);
    t.start();
  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    Date d = new Date();
    setText(sdf.format(d));
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe it has something to do with the fact that you're calling `Thread.sleep(60000*60);` which is NOT 1 minute - it is 1 hour... This is putting the GUI to sleep for an hour. If you want to cancel the timer task after a minute, you should schedule a different timer task to run after one minute (1000 * 60) which will call `cancel` on the first timer task. Basically, get that Thread.sleep() OFF of the UI thread!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, actually I already know that, what I really mean is whether `TimerTask` can run simultaneously with the GUI without waiting for` TimerTask` to finish. Such as `TimerTask` runs behind the GUI. Is it possible in java?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are putting the UI thread to sleep, and it looks like you are sleeping for longer than you think you are... 60000 * 60 = one hour!

```
public void scan() throws SQLException{

    java.util.TimerTask task = new java.util.TimerTask()  {
        // ...
    };

    timer = new Timer(true);// true to run timer as daemon thread
    timer.schedule(task, 0, 5000);// Run task every 5 second
    try {
        //--------------------------------------------------
        //    This is putting the UI to sleep for an hour!
        //--------------------------------------------------
        Thread.sleep(60000*60); // Cancel task after 1 minute. <-- NOT 1 minute!
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    timer.cancel();
}
```

You should try to get all of that business onto a separate thread. It could be done like this:

```
public void scan() throws SQLException{

    Runnable scanRunner = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            java.util.TimerTask task = new java.util.TimerTask()  {
                // ...
            };

            timer = new Timer(true);// true to run timer as daemon thread
            timer.schedule(task, 0, 5000);// Run task every 5 second
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000*60); // Cancel task after 1 minute.
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            timer.cancel();
        }
    };

    new Thread(scanRunner).start();
}
```

As a side note, there are likely a lot of other issues doing it this way since you could check/uncheck the box in the UI at your leisure, and it would not stop any previous scan tasks... I'll let you manage that situation yourself, or ask a different question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers, actually I already know that, what I really mean is whether `TimerTask` can run simultaneously with the GUI without waiting for` TimerTask` to finish. Such as `TimerTask` runs behind the GUI. Is it possible in java?

Comment: @adjieq The JVM will close (automatically) when the only running threads a daemon threads - so you will want to change `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` for a start

Comment: Yes, the TimerTask can run simultaneously with the GUI. It runs on a separate thread. The frozen GUI comes when you use Thread.sleep() within the UI thread. If you did not Thread.sleep(), then your GUI would still respond while the TimerTask runs in the background.